# How to get 32-bit color in a Windows RDP session

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, colors, 32-bit

I was able to setup Windows Server to allow 32-bit color in RDP sessions. I want to do the same thing for Windows XP. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Click on Start -> Run. type `mstsc`. The RDC connection windows opens, head over to display tab and under Colours, select Highest quality (32-bit).

Comment: That doesn't do anything. Is that  a typo?

Comment: Nope. @awake AFAIK only difference between 24-bit & 32-bit is an alpha channel

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the Remote Desktop Client to version 6.0 from the Microsoft download site at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925876

The 5.0 version that ships with XP only supports 24-bit, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: As far as you're concerned?  Is this poor word choice or are you saying it does support but the implementation is lousy?  (Not nitpicking, just interested in clarity since I don't know this myself.)

Comment: That's the client. If the server doesn't support 32-bit how is that going to help?